# MSTest + CHESS in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest

Can I unit test my multi-threaded code using CHESS & MSTest in VS 2010. I tried this

```
[TestMethod]
[HostType("Chess")]
[TestProperty("ChessExpectedResult", "deadlock")]
public void TestMyMethod()
{
...
}
```

but I get the following error

```
The host type 'Chess' cannot be loaded for the following reason: The key 'Chess' cannot be found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, CHESS only supports Visual Studio 2008.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/download.aspx